# How to use history as one of the input in neural networks?

Tags: list-manipulation, core-language, functional-style, machine-learning, neural-networks

Suppose I have a net

```
SeedRandom[1234];
net = NetInitialize@NetGraph[{ReshapeLayer[{4, 8}], 
                              BasicRecurrentLayer[8], SequenceLastLayer[], 
                              CatenateLayer[], 8, Ramp, 8}, 
                             {NetPort["history"] -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4, 
                              NetPort["Input1"] -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7}, 
                             "history" -> 8*4, 
                             "Input1" -> 40]
```

[image]

This is the `Input1`,it has 20 examples.

```
data = RandomReal[1, {20, 40}];
```

Because of the output of this net has 8-dims `Output`.

Four past outputs constitute the 32-dims vector and the net use this vector and `Input1` to predict next `history`.

*Assuming at time 1,there is no history and `history` is all zero.*

time 1:

```
net[<|"Input1" -> data[[1]], "history" ->      ConstantArray[0, 8*4]|>]
```

time 2:

```
net[<|"Input1" -> data[[2]], "history" -> Join[ConstantArray[0, 8*3], %]|>]
```

time 3:

```
net[<|"Input1" -> data[[3]], "history" -> Join[ConstantArray[0, 8*2], %%, %]|>]
```

time 4:

```
net[<|"Input1" -> data[[4]], "history" -> Join[ConstantArray[0, 8*1], %%%, %%, %]|>]
```

time 5:

```
net[<|"Input1" -> data[[5]], "history" -> Join[%%%%, %%%, %%, %]|>]
```

time 6:

```
net[<|"Input1" -> data[[6]], "history" -> Join[%%%%, %%%, %%, %]|>]
```

[image]

...

time 20:

```
net[<|"Input1" -> data[[20]], "history" -> Join[%%%%, %%%, %%, %]|>]
```

I try this code but it can not be combined with other codes well.

***And it mismatch the result at time 6***

```
out = ConstantArray[0, {20, 8}];
out[[1]] = net[<|"Input1" -> data[[1]], "history" -> ConstantArray[0, 8*4]|>];
out[[2]] = net[<|"Input1" -> data[[2]], "history" -> Join[ConstantArray[0, 8*3], %]|>];
out[[3]] = net[<|"Input1" -> data[[3]], "history" -> Join[ConstantArray[0, 8*2], %%, %]|>];
out[[4]] = net[<|"Input1" -> data[[4]], "history" -> Join[ConstantArray[0, 8*1], %%%, %%, %]|>];
Do[out[[i]] = net[<|"Input1" -> data[[i]], 
                    "history" -> Join[%%%%, %%%, %%, %]|>], {i, 5, 20}]
```

[image]

So is there a nice way or a **functional style** to implement this and got the `Output` from time 1 to 20?

How can trace the recent four historical results,`FoldList` can do it?

Comment: Nice question, looks like a task for SequenceFold, surprised there's no answer yet. +1

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Nice to hear that :)

Comment: Self-answers are encouraged here. If you think you've achieved your goals, why not transfer your update to a proper answer?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP right ,thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Thanks LLlAMnYP,I try `SequenceFoldList` and find it can generate interesting result.**

```
SequenceFoldList[f, {0, 0, 0, 0}, Range[5], 4] // Column
```

[image]

So I am sure it can be used in here.

```
Module[{i = 1}, Drop[#, 4] &@
   SequenceFoldList[
     net[<|"Input1" -> data[[i++]], 
           "history" -> Flatten@{##}|>] &, 
     {ConstantArray[0, 8], ConstantArray[0, 8], ConstantArray[0, 8],ConstantArray[0, 8]}, 
     Range[Length@data-1], 4]] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

It got a correct result.